# Как инициализировать GLAD в Gtk+ C++

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk, gtk+

Мне нужно добавить в приложении на Gtk+ окошко, в котором будет отображаться OpenGL - код. Уже разобрался с тем, что нужно использовать core-profile стиль с шейдерами прочим делом. Но проблема в том, что шейдеры не запускаются, если не инициализирован GLAD. Я разобрался как инициализировать его с помощью GLFW

```
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(400, 400, "Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, NULL);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

Однако в таком случае создается ненужное мне GLFW-окошко, что видно на скриншоте ниже. Как можно обойтись без GLFW, чтобы инициализировать GLAD?
Если его не инициализировать, то он сходу ругается на функции типа glGenBuffers или glCreateShader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понял, что это мне все было не нужно. Поставил GLEW и все заработало. В нем для того, чтобы включить возможность работы с core-profile нужно лишь выполнить следующие:

```
glewExperimental = true;
glewInit();
```